# If Statement using PHP Echo and isEqualToString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am going absolutely crazy trying to figure out what I am doing wrong below. I have a PHP file that echoes a 0 or a 1 depending on some calculations. If the result is 0, I would like to display one alert. If the result is 1, I would like to display a different alert.

Strangely, when I include the string returned from the PHP file (named `aroundURLString` below) in the alert, it displays correctly. (what I mean by this is that the 'message' field of the alert is working and is proving that the PHP file is returning the right value....)

However, my issue is that the if statements are not working as I would expect. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Im going crazy trying to figure this out. Thank you!

```
    NSData *aroundURLResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
    URLWithString:aroundURL]];

    // to receive the returend value
    NSString *aroundURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:aroundURLResult 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([aroundURLString isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"the string is 0" 
        message:aroundURLString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
        otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    if ([aroundURLString isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"the string is 1" 
        message:aroundURLString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
        otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
```

Comment: thanks! checking to see if this is a duplicate.

Comment: It's not uncommon for there to be a newline or some other whitespace as part of the response.

Comment: looks like it might work. if so I will close. thanks for identifying that!

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks @rmaddy! Closing now.